# Can Swedish wheels be used in two wheeler configuration?

Tags: kinematics, wheeled-robot, forward-kinematics, two-wheeled, wheel

Can we use any of the Swedish 90°/45° Omni or Mecanum wheels in two wheeler configurations?

Comment: Can you please specify your exact design criteria...? Why you think two wheel config with appropriate balancing control in a 2 degree freedom system isnt possible?

Answer (score 1):

*This started out as a comment but I ran out of space. Also, I am waiting for the question to be clarified, as morbo has requested of the OP.*

---

Here is an example on YouTube, [Lego Technic two-wheeled double track tank r/c omni-wheel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvhPiTOGBb8), although I must say that the wheels do not look particularly *omni* to me:

[image: Lego Technic two-wheeled double track tank r/c omni-wheel]

Whilst this is not particular to Omni/Mecanum wheels, it is worth noting that a robot with a two wheeled differential drive can achieve stability if the center of mass is below the wheel axle or if there is a third point of contact striking the floor.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose yes, one could. They are wheels after all.

This mostly depends on other things, such as your design and how you want to move (in actual omnidirection? keeping balancing will be difficult, but it is possible.) ...a wheel is a wheel, regardless of if it's an omnidirectional one or not.

An example of a spherical wheel being used in a two wheel system I've heard of is the [omni directional motorcycle.](https://newatlas.com/spherical-drive-system-omnidirectional-electric-motorcycle/24095/?utm_source=Gizmag%20Subscribers&utm_campaign=6524605ed8-UA-2235360-4&utm_medium=email#gallery)

Comment: I can't see how either omni or mecanum wheels could be used in a two wheel configuration, but I don't understand the kinematic equations well enough to be able to answer this fully. Certainly the minimum configuration I could find required was three wheels. I recently saw a wheelchair design which used two omni wheels and two normal wheels, but it obviously had manoeuvring and stability issues on tilted surfaces in the video.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* morbo. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations.

Comment: I would request that the OP would be more specific in their design criteria before i can give a more fully detailed answer.

Comment: The issue with stability re: wheelchair with 2x omniwheels is present with nearly all powerchairs with 2WD and castors - it's a real problem for users.

Comment: I never said it wasnt difficult, i simply said it *is* possible...one just has think of a stability system...think of a rolling inverse spherical pendulum and how one would keep such a system inverted or clever positioning of the c.o.g....as mentioned in greenonlines answer. here it would be similar